# How to export function as a class?

Tags: inheritance, typescript

I'd like to make a class based on array with additional method `get`.
Initially my code looked like that:

```
export class CircularArray extends Array<string> {
    constructor(data: string[]) {
        super();
        this.push(...data);
    }

    get(i: number): string {
        return this[i % this.length];
    }
}
```

In typescript 2.0.10 it worked perfectly. But when I desided to update typescript to actual version 2.2.0, I found out that compilation of this code [have changed](//www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=export%20class%20CircularArray%20extends%20Array%3Cstring%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(data%3A%20string%5B%5D)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20super()%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.push(...data)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20get(i%3A%20number)%3A%20string%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20this%5Bi%20%25%20this.length%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A): now typescript handles the value returned from the `super()` call:

```
function CircularArray(data) {
    var _this = _super.call(this) || this;
    _this.push.apply(_this, data);
    return _this;
}
```

So the returned object is result of the call to `Array`. Of course, its prototype is `Array.prototype` instead of `CircularArray.prototype` and method `get` is lost. How can I fix it?

I've tried to do something like that:

```
export declare class CircularArray extends Array<string> {
    constructor(data: string[]);
    get(i: number): string;
}

export function CircularArray(data: string[]): CircularArray {
    this.push(...data);
    return this;
};

CircularArray.prototype = Object.create(Array.prototype);

CircularArray.prototype.get = function (i: number): string {
    return this[i % this.length];
};
```

but got a error:

> error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'CircularArray'.
>   error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'CircularArray'.

PS: [Same question in Russian.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/630321/178988)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
export interface CircularArray extends Array<string> {
    constructor(data: string[]): CircularArray;
    get(i: number): string;
}

export var CircularArray: { new (data: string[]): CircularArray } = function CircularArray(data: string[]): void {
    this.push(...data);
} as any;

CircularArray.prototype = Object.create(Array.prototype);

CircularArray.prototype.get = function (i: number): string {
    return this[i % this.length];
};
```